# Find position of matched word in a line in bash (not position of character)

Tags: bash, array

I have a line like

```
Xckt VDD VSS sig[1] sig[2] sig[3] sig[4] sig[5] sig[6] CKT
```

and I want to find the position of sig[4] in the line. In this case it should return **7**. I wanted some simple script/ one liner in bash to do the same.
In case of repeated match, if serial number of all occurrences of the match in the line would be great.

Comment: If any of the existing answers solves your problem, please consider accepting it via the checkmark. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with `awk` like this:

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i=="sig[4]")print i}'
```

That should work for you even in case of multiple entries.

If you need all the numbers on the same line, you can replace `print` with `printf` and adjust accordingly.

Comment: `echo 'Xckt VDD VSS sig[1] sig[2] sig[3] sig[4] sig[5] sig[6] CKT' | grep -aob 'sig\[4]'`
Returns: 34:sig[4]
I needed the position of the word rather than the 1st character for the match in the line. Th expected answer for me is 7 unline 34 coming from *"grep -aob"*

Comment: yep, you are write. sorry I read the question a bit inattentively. the answer is updated.

Answer (score 1):

[rush has a nice one-liner solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/278807/117549); here's a simple bash function that prints out all of the matches in the string:

```bash
function pratappos() {
  target=$1; shift
  pos=1
  while [[ $# -gt 0 ]]
  do
    [[ "$1" = "$target" ]] && echo $pos
    shift; ((++pos))
  done
  unset target pos
}
```

It's generalized to search for any string in a given list, so for example, you would set up that function (in your .bashrc, or into your current shell), then call it like:

```
pratappos sig[4] Xckt VDD VSS sig[1] sig[2] sig[3] sig[4] sig[5] sig[6] CKT
7
```

or (two matches):

```
pratappos sig[4] Xckt VDD VSS sig[1] sig[2] sig[3] sig[4] sig[5] sig[6] CKT sig[4]
7
11
```

... where the first parameter that you pass to it is taken as the string you want to search for, followed by the rest of the string to search in. It determines the position of the arguments using `shift`, which will see your given string as separated by $IFS.

To clarify the preceding point:

```
pratappos 'foo bar' a b foo bar 'foo bar' rest here
5
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with `perl`, for example using the List::MoreUtils module as described in [[perl] Get indexes of matches in array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4040178/4440445)

```
perl -MList::MoreUtils=indexes -alne '
  print $_+1 for indexes { $_ eq "sig[4]" } @F
'
```

Testing with the given input line

```
$ perl -MList::MoreUtils=indexes -alne '
  print $_+1 for indexes { $_ eq "sig[4]" } @F
' <<< "Xckt VDD VSS sig[1] sig[2] sig[3] sig[4] sig[5] sig[6] CKT"
7
```

and with a line containing multiple instances

```
$ perl -MList::MoreUtils=indexes -alne '
  print $_+1 for indexes { $_ eq "sig[4]" } @F
' <<< "Xckt VDD VSS sig[1] sig[2] sig[3] sig[4] sig[5] sig[6] sig[4] CKT"
7
10
```